# How to calculate the market cap of a company before and after IPO

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

When I calculate the market cap of a company before IPO, I just go to the latest S-1 form and find "Weighted-average shares used in computing net loss per share attributable to common stockholders, basic and diluted".

Then, I multiply the IPO stock price by the number of shares I found.

For an after IPO company, I just go to the latest 10-Q form and find "Weighted-average shares used in computing net loss per share attributable to common stockholders, basic and diluted".

Then, I multiply the current stock price by the number of shares I found.

Is my method correct?